# Yeoman use install a generator to install webapp and not working

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I am using `yeoman` to install webapp but I have this error. I am new to `nodejs` and all this, but when I install it on other computers no error happens, so how do I fix this.

error

```
npm isParseError: Unexpected token '<' at 2:1 in http://registry.npmjs.org/-/_view/byKeyword?startkey=[%22yeoman-generator%22]&endkey=[%22yeoman-generator%22,%7B%7D]&group_level=3 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ^
at C:\Users\_monster\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\npm-keyword\node_modules\got\index.js:120:14
at BufferStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\_monster\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\read-all-stream\index.js:64:3)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at BufferStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
at finishMaybe (C:\Users\_monster\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:607:14)
at endWritable (C:\Users\_monster\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:615:3)
at BufferStream.Writable.end (C:\Users\_monster\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:571:41)
at IncomingMessage.onend (_stream_readable.js:511:10)
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```

Comment: Please show us which command you typed.

Comment: i am install yeoman buy using "npm install yo -g , then i type yo and select install a web generator and type webapp .

Comment: can you specify OS version and type, node version npm version and web app type and language